# php - set html hyperlink with onClick as string

Tags: php

any ideas why this does not work?

```
$pem = 'hello';
$view_pem = "<a onClick='function('<?php echo $pem ?>');'>View PEM</a>";

echo $view_pem;
```

I simply want to use onClick to echo a string but im unable to make it work.
With the above code, my link ends up looking like this `?>')'>View PEM` and doesnt work.

I also tried putting the php tag inside double quotes but then it complains `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?'`

hopefully this is an easy fix?

Comment: What do you mean by "echo a string"? Do you mean append it to the document when the user clicks the link, or show a popup? Also, your syntax is a bit off, but one step at a time.

Comment: yes, append to document would be correct

Comment: `$view_pem = '<a onClick="function(\''. str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $pem) .'\');">View PEM</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
      $pem = 'hello';
      $view_pem = "<a onClick='function(\"$pem\")' href='javascript:void(0);'>View PEM</a>";

       echo $view_pem;
```